# Using 'let' too many times?

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

When I begin a proof, I need to define certain things. for example the classic:
$$
\text{Let } \epsilon > 0.
$$
However, it seems that there are times where I need to define a lot of things in this way:
$$
\text{Let } f = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \chi_{I_i} \text{ and } g = \sum_{j=1}^{m} \beta_j \chi_{J_j} \text{ and let } c \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
$$ 
\text{ Then, let } c \alpha_i + \beta_j = \gamma_{i+n(j-1)} \text{ and let } I_i \cap J_j = K_{i+n(j-1)}.
$$

I feel like there might be a better way to phrase such things, but there's nothing I can think of. Am I using 'let' too many times? Or is this just the way I have to do it?

Comment: Try "take," or "suppose," or "set."

Comment: Let me think about that....

Comment: Some alternatives that should work in most cases: "define", "put", "suppose that"

Comment: Fix $\epsilon>0$... pick... define... assume that

Comment: You could also say let the following be defined and define everything at once. In your line that defines $f$ and $g$ you could replace "and let $c\in\mathbb R$" with "with $ c\in\mathbb R$". In your last line you only need one let before the "and" phrase.

Comment: @KevinCarlson and Bungo: switching between "let", "take", "suppose" and "set" to make the narrative more interesting is deeply confusing to readers. "Suppose" is confusing because it suggests an assumption rather than a definition. On the other hand, "let $\epsilon > 0$" is stating an assumption and not a definition.  It is better to say something like  "let $f$, $g$ and .. be defined as follows if you have many variables to define by equations and something like "suppose $\epsilon$, $\delta$ and .. are real numbers (or whatever) satisfying $\ldots$ for variables subject to assumptions.

Comment: @RobArthan I agree that the words have different meanings and wouldn't recommend cycling them completely interchangeably. That said, I think that in most cases this kind of thing is a mild danger.